# convolution neural network training taking substantial amount of time (using keras)

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using cifar-10 dataset for training CNN .
I am using my windows-10 laptop ,keras version - 2.2.4 and python - 3.7 
I have built the CNN using keras using one of the example from learnopencv.com . 
I am using batch_size=256 and epochs=50

Each Epoch is taking close to 1000 secs , making 50 epochs = 50000 secs ~ 13 hours, which is very high .

My windows laptop is having 4 cpus , as confirmed by following python code .

```
import os
print(os.cpu_count())
```

Is there way to introduce parallelism in the training ( for example use all 4 cpus ) and reduce training time by factor of 4 ? . 
Renting  aws machine with gpu would be another option , however it would be incurring cost. g3s.xlarge charge is about .45 dollars per hour .

Example code used for building the model is as below .

```
from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Dense , Conv2D ,Flatten,Dropout
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.build()
from keras.datasets import cifar10

(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np 
nClasses = np.unique(y_train)

nRows,nCols,nDims = x_train.shape[1:]

train_data = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], nRows, nCols, nDims)
test_data = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], nRows, nCols, nDims)

train_data = train_data.astype('float32')
test_data = test_data.astype('float32')

train_data /= 255
test_data /= 255

train_labels_one_hot = to_categorical(y_train)
test_labels_one_hot = to_categorical(y_test)

batch_size=256
epochs=50 

history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels_one_hot, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, 
                   validation_data=(test_data, test_labels_one_hot))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run CNNs in parallel then you will have the problem of how to accumulate the gradients and how to update a single model. It is  very tricky and AI companies are working on it.

If your goal is learning then try a smaller data set like MINST rather then cifar. You can also increase the epoch speed by reducing the depth of your CNN model ie. cut down some layers. Again if you goal is purely to learn you can work on down scaled images which will decrease the number of model weights and so decrease the training time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions . will try reducing the depth . One point on size of dataset . cifar10 is 50000  images of size 32*32  , while mnist consists of  60000 images of size 28*28 . Both dataset appear very similar in size.

Comment: @TanmayPatil You are correct but they are gray scale (single channel).

Comment: I tried in google colab with gpu as runtime , it takes 10 sec for one epoch .But this gpu is shared it seems ( as per some of the stackoverflow replies )